# Given $U$ vectorial space, find a linear functional such that $U=f^{-1}(\beta)$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Given a vector space $V$ with $\dim(V)=n$, an affine subspace $W$ with $\dim(W)=n-1$, $x\in V$ and $K\subset V$ compact and convex with $W\cap K = \{x\}$, find a linear functional $f:V\to\Bbb R$ such that $W=\{y\in V~|~f(y)= f(x) \}$, with $f(x)=\sup_{y\in K}f(y)$.

Any hint will be very helpful.

Comment: Are you allowed to use some form of separation theorem?

Comment: Nits: $a$ and $x$ are used without being introduced (i.e. without specifying their containing sets).

Comment: Are you able to solve it if we replace $\beta$ with $0$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Like the Banach Separation Theorem (about half-spaces)? In this case, yes, this would be nice to use it

Comment: @EricTowers $a, x \in V$. Just added to the question. And for your second question: I don't know =(

Comment: @Redshoes Thank you for the edit. That is what I wanted for sure. I edited the question to fit the true problem.

Comment: @EricTowers The question was edited as a suggestion by Red Shoes. The problem is actually the case $\beta=0$.

Comment: The question don't fill my purposes at all, it is wrong, but now, due to the everyone's help, I can see how to solve all my problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a functional may not exist at all!! You would have to assume at least that $b\notin ri(K)$. Consider

$$V= \mathbb{R}^2,\; U=\{(x,y)\in V: x=0\}.$$ Also, put $a=x=(0,0),\; b= (1,0)$ and

$$K=[0,2]\times \{0\}.$$ Assume that a functional $f$ satisfying your conditions exist. So there exists $m,n\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$f(x,y)=mx+ny.$$ Note that since $U$ is a subspace and the level set of a linear functional, it can only be $\beta=0.$ This means that $U$ is necesarily the Kernel of $f,$ and so we will have $n=0.$ Hence $f(x,y)=mx.$ We must also have

$$f(x,y)\leq f(b)\;\forall\;(x,y)\in K,$$ which is equivalent to

$$mx\leq f(b)=m \;\forall\; x\in [0,2],$$ a contradiction.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ Since the question was edited, now I will show that this new statement is not true either.

Choose $$V= \mathbb{R}^2,\; U=\{(x,y)\in V: x=0\}$$ and $K=[-1,1]\times\{0\}.$ Hence $x=(0,0).$ Assume that such a functional $f$ exists. Then necessarily $f(x)=0$ Then, if $f(y_1,y_2)=my_1+ny_2,$ we must have

$$U=\{y \in V: f(y)=0\},$$ or $n=0.$ Then we should have

$$f(y)= my_1\leq 0=f(x)$$ for each $y_1\in [-1,1],$ a contradiction.